# How to disable Stock Status in Advance Inventory section under product page

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, stock-availability, component-manager

I need to disable stock status field under advance inventory section in the product page.

[image]

I don't want to remove it but show it disabled. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

To disable the Stock Status field in Advance Inventory on the magento admin product page.

Override the 'vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml' file.

Add the `'<disabled>true</disabled>'` attribute in the 'Stock Status' field setting.

Comment: I have already tried but it only makes the select element grey out and the option selection is still working. The disable attribute was not added to the select element as property making it still available to change the option.